# population of about one million / population about one million

Tags: prepositions

> The capital city, Washington, has a population **of** about one million.

Why is it necessary to use "of" here? If we say the sentence without "of", is it a mistake or another meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say "The population of Washington **is** about one million.", but in the form you are using, without the linking verb **is**, you should use **of**.
You could also use the preposition **at**, if you are underlining its present level while discussing change, for example,
Washington has a population currently **at** about 1 million.

If you were answering a question where the linking verb is implied, you wouldn't use **of**, for example,
Q. What is the population of Washington?
A. About one million.

In *about one million*, the word *about* isn't a preposition, but an adverb.